Carmichael function not incrementing k
For any number, the Carmichael function returns 0 no matter what the input n is.
function gcd(a, b)
  if b == 0 then
    return a
  else
    return (gcd(b,a%b))
  end
end

function carmichael(n)
  coprimes = {}
  for i = 1,n-1 do
    if gcd(i,n) == 1 then
      table.insert(coprimes,i)
    end
  end
  k = 0
  while true do
    for counter = 1,#coprimes do
      coprime = coprimes[counter]
      if (coprime^k)%n ~= 1 then
        break
      else
        return k
      end
      k = k+1
    end
  end
end

input = io.read()

print(carmichael(tonumber(input)))


If coprime = 1 then (coprime^k)%n is 1, so it goes to the else part and just return k

So how exactly world I modify the function so that this problem would no longer occur?

What do you want to do with k? What is the expected output of camichael(n)?

The expected output is the Carmichael number of n, basically the smallest number of the set of real integers that has the property a^m = 1 (mod n) holds for every integer coprime to n here

Read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761383/proper-carmichael-function, then apply what that teaches you in a Lua context?

One possible way is to not "return after just one match", but rather use a variable to check whether the loop was broken. If it goes outside the for loop without breaking, then all the coprime numbers satisfy the condition, otherwise go to the next k. However, I am thinking of another problem, namely whether coprime^k exceeds the maximum integer in Lua

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the only answer to this question is not a "proper" Carmichael function because it does not make sure that all coprimes meet the condition a^m%n=1, only one, resulting in the output of the function always being 0

I fixed the code by adding a check to see if the loop was broken and modified the check to make sure that all coprimes met the condition using k, and changed the assignment value of k from 0 to 1, so that coprime^k%n does not always evaluate to 1, because all numbers to the power of 0 result in 1. Modified code:
function carmichael(n)
  coprimes = {}
  for i = 1,n-1 do
    if gcd(i,n) == 1 then
      table.insert(coprimes,i)
    end
  end
  totient = #coprimes
  k = 1
  while k <= totient do
    notcarmichael = false
    for counter = 1,#coprimes do
      coprime = coprimes[counter]
      if (coprime^k)%n ~= 1 then
        notcarmichael = true
        break
      end
    end
    if not notcarmichael then
      return k
    else
      k = k+1
    end
  end
  return totient
end


Should be fine for smaller numbers, but if coprime^k results in a very big number, then it may result in weird behaviors. To see what I mean by "very big", try unsafe_int = 2^53; print(unsafe_int == unsafe_int+1) which prints true. Anything bigger than the value 9007199254740991 reference
